# Nuget 2.5 fails with "This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms

Tags: nuget

For nuget version 2.2.40207.9053 this works:

```
.\NuGet.exe install
```

(given there is a packages.config file in the same folder).

The same command for version 2.5.40412.9018 fails with:

> This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.

We're on Windows Server 2012.

What do I need to do to get it to work with v2.5?

Out of curiosity, what has changed in v2.5 and why?